# Firebase, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Добрый день. Понадобилось воспользоваться сервисом "Firebase". Посмотрел уроки, у всех есть данный пункт меню во вкладке tools. У меня его нет. В SDK Tolls все необходимые галочки стоят. Подскажите как можно добавить этот пункт?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновить Android Studio.

Comment: У меня эта кнопка есть, но ни разу её использовать не доводилось, хоть и работал с Firebase. Т.е. она не нужна

Comment: У меня стоит последняя версия Андроид Студио

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это плагин Firebase Services. Включите\установите его через настройки: Settings.. -> Plugins: чекбокс на Firebase Services

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]